# How can i avoid the Processing default GUI?

Tags: processing

I want to create a Processing command-line server-application.

How can I avoid the Default Processing GUI (pApplet)?

Comment: Did you try the command-line application? http://wiki.processing.org/w/Command_Line

Comment: Command-Line is just a way to compile Processing-code via commandline but it does not avoid the pApplet

Comment: Processing's main advantage over raw java is for graphical coding. Perhaps you could provide some info about what you want to do? Processing seems an odd choice for a generic server program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use Processing environment from within a standard Java application. [Here](http://www.ctctlabs.com/index.php/blog/detail/how_to_use_processing_from_the_command_line_to_generate_images/) is some tutorial for generating images without Processing window.